# How am I supposed to manage db revisions alongside codebase revisions?

Tags: database, git, version-control, rake

We have a Rails app with a PostgreSQL database. We use `git` for version control.

We're only two developers on the project, so we both have to do a little of everything, and when emergencies arise we often have to drop everything to address them.

We have a main branch (called `staging` just to be difficult ) which we only use directly for quick fixes, minor copy changes, etc. For bigger features, we work on independent feature branches.

When I work on a feature that requires changes to the database, I naturally have to create migrations that alter the schema. Let's say I'm working on `feature-emoji`, and I create a migration `20150706101741_add_emoji_to_users.rb`. I run `rake db:migrate` to get on with my work.

Later, I'm informed of some bug I need to address. I switch to `staging` to start work on it; however, now my app will misbehave because the db schema does not match what the app expects. So *before* doing `git checkout staging`, I have to remember to do `rake db:rollback`. And then later when I switch back to `feature-emoji`, I have to run `rake db:migrate` again.

This whole flow is sort of okay-ish when dealing with just two branches, but when the `git rebase`s and `git merge`s happen, it gets complicated.

Is there no better way to handle versioning of code and db in parallel? Or am I doomed to have to run annoying `rake` tasks every time I want to change branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy answer to this. You could perhaps set up something like a git hook to check for changes to `schema.rb`, and fail the checkout if any are present; but there are lots of edge cases to check for in such a setup.

Ultimately, the responsibility lies with the human developer to restore untracked parts of their environment — e.g. the database — to a clean state before switching branches.